# TypeError: hp_choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, hyperopt, hyperas

I'm trying to do hyperparameter optimization to this keras model with the hyperas library, I've never done this before so I basically followed the step-by-step complete example [here](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas) but I'm getting the error mentioned. Thanks in advance.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 input_shape=input_shape, activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 input_shape=input_shape, activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 input_shape=input_shape, activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 input_shape=input_shape, activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(Conv2D({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}}, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                 activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}},
                activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 0.75)}}))

model.add(Dense({{choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)}},
                activation={{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))
model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 0.75)}}))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation({{choice('relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh')}}))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer={{choice(RMSprop, Adam, SGD)}},
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

> ````
> "/home/bjorn/PycharmProjects/Test/HyperoptModel.py", line 113, in
> <module>
>     trials=Trials())   File "/home/bjorn/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/hyperas/optim.py",
> line 69, in minimize
>     keep_temp=keep_temp)   File "/home/bjorn/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/hyperas/optim.py",
> line 134, in base_minimizer
>     space=get_space(),   File "/home/bjorn/PycharmProjects/Test/temp_model.py", line 149, in
> get_space   File
> "/home/bjorn/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/hyperopt/pyll_utils.py",
> line 22, in wrapper
>     return f(label, *args, **kwargs) TypeError: hp_choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given ```
> ````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the options for `choice` as a `list` instead as multiple parameters.

change

```
choice(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)
```

to

```
choice([32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!